# What are the orders about praying on bare floor to join Jamaat?

Tags: salat, jamaat

In our office the praying area space is quite small. Most of the time when in Jamat the carpet  runs short and people join prayer on plain floor, and they put paper on the spot of Sajda.

Is it allowed to join Jamat in any case even you have to offer it on bare floor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no restriction to praying on any medium, as long as it is "Tahir" (طاهر). There were no carpets in mosques for at least 40 years after Hijrah (الهجرة). The Prophet (saaw) had a sandy floor (or actually no floor). Omar Ibn ElKhattab (ra) introduced gravel to the mosque's floor, and it wasn't until the era of the Omayyad state that carpets were introduced in mosques.

There were also recorded cases for companions praying in mud during rains. In short, pray on any floor you wish.

Comment: can you cite the source for praying in mud during rain? I would like to evaluate what to do when its raining and time to pray

Comment: @AadilAhmed You can find some information here: http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=682&idto=684&bk_no=15&ID=650